# iOS 3rd Party Keyboard Cell Subtitle

Tags: ios

I have an app that provides a 3rd party keyboard for iOS and on the screen where the user adds the keyboard into the system, there is a subtitle within the cell that doesn't look great. I have already tried the `Bundle display name` within the keyboard's Info.plist but that makes no difference. How do I change this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i am not sure about a custom description in the cell but i know that you can change this title in the info plist for the keyboard under

> NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> PrimaryLanguage

Then you can set that to a specific string for the languages your keyboard can speak. e.g. en-us or mul (multiple languages)

As they say a picture speaks a thousand words, so image attached

[image: Image below]